# SQL Server window function time based data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-partitioning

I'm running SQL Server 2016 and I have a set of data that looks like this

```
Name    Time                    Type
CL1 2018-05-22 10:50:00 -04:00  SampleAndTrade
CL1 2018-05-22 11:00:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 11:10:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 11:20:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 14:10:00 -04:00  SampleAndTrade
CL1 2018-05-22 14:20:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 14:30:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 14:40:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
CL1 2018-05-22 14:50:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 10:50:00 -04:00  SampleAndTrade
HO1 2018-05-22 11:00:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 11:10:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 11:20:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 14:10:00 -04:00  SampleAndTrade
HO1 2018-05-22 14:20:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 14:30:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 14:40:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
HO1 2018-05-22 14:50:00 -04:00  TradeOnly
```

A trade period starts with a `SampleAndTrade` and ends with a `TradeOnly` (before the next `SampleAndTrade`). You will always have at least one `TradeOnl`y After a `SampleAndTrade`. The interval will always be uniform across a single trade. I would like to transpose this data so that it looks like this:

```
Name    StartTime    EndTime   IntervalMin
CL1     10:50        11:20     10
CL1     14:10        14:50     10
HO1     10:50        11:20     10
HO1     14:10        14:50     10
```

I really can't figure out how to partition the data correctly to roll up over trade cycles. Could anyone give me a hint as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: Can you state your sql server version? Because from 2012+ some analytic functions may be handy...Also: What about IntervalMin? What if you had 10:00 sample&trade, then 10:10 tradeonly, then 10:30 tradeonly?

Comment: Edited above: SQL Server 2016. THe intervals will all be of the same length for any trade cycle. A trade cycle is a SampleAndTrade followed by any number of TradeOnly. Overlapping isn't allowed

Comment: Could you have any instances of two `SampleAndTrade` rows with no intervening `TradeOnly` rows? If so, what should happen there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Name,
  MIN(Time)   AS StartTime,
  MAX(Time)   AS EndTime,
  MIN(Diff)   AS IntervalMin
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'SampleAndTrade' THEN 1 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY Name
                ORDER BY Time
           )
             AS GroupID,
    DATEDIFF(
      MINUTE,
      LAG(Time)
        OVER (PARTITION BY Name
                  ORDER BY Time
             ),
      Time
    )
      AS Diff
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS summary
GROUP BY
  Name,
  GroupID
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

You just need to assign a group by doing a cumulative sum of the `'SampleAndTrade'`.  Then aggregation:

```
select name, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 'SampleAndTrade' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by name, grp;
```

I'm not sure how `intervalmin` is calculated.  Perhaps:

```
datediff(minute, min(time), max(time)) / count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *correlation* approach for older version

```
with tt as (
 select *, 
       (select count(*) 
        from table 
        where Name = t.name and  [type] = 'SampleAndTrade' and time <= t.time
        ) as Seq
 from table t
)

select Name, min(time), max(time), 
       datediff(minute, min(time), max(time)) as IntervalMin
from tt
group by Name, Seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(20), tm datetime2, Type varchar(20));
insert into @t values 
('CL1', '2018-05-22 10:50:00 -04:00', 'SampleAndTrade'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 11:00:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 11:10:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 11:20:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 14:10:00 -04:00', 'SampleAndTrade'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 14:20:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 14:30:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 14:40:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('CL1', '2018-05-22 14:50:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 10:50:00 -04:00', 'SampleAndTrade'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 11:00:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 11:10:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 11:20:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 14:10:00 -04:00', 'SampleAndTrade'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 14:20:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 14:30:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 14:40:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly'),
('HO1', '2018-05-22 14:50:00 -04:00', 'TradeOnly');
with cte as 
( select t1.* 
       , lead(type) over (partition by name order by tm) as nextType
  from @t t1 
)
select t1.Name, t1.tm, min(t2.tm) 
   --, t1.Type, t2.tm, t2.nextType
  from cte t1 
  join cte t2 
    on t1.Name = t2.Name 
   and t1.Type = 'SampleAndTrade' 
   and (t2.nextType = 'SampleAndTrade' or t2.nextType is null)
   and t2.tm > t1.tm
 group by t1.Name, t1.tm
 order by t1.name, t1.tm
```